Flutter MainAxisAlignment spaceEvenly not working when Row is inside a SingleChildScrollView
I have a Row with 3 Text widgets. I would like them to be spaced evenly:
item1      item2      item3

However I also want to make sure that there is no overflow if the Text widgets take up too much space horizontally. That is why I decided to wrap the Row inside a SingleChildScrollView and set the scroll direction to Axis.horizontal. But when I set the scrollDirection property it removed the mainAxisAlginment property of the Row children:

item1 item2 item3

Here is my code:
              const SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text("item1: item1_value"),
                    Text("item2: item2_value"),
                    Text("item3: item3_value")
                  ],
                ),
              )

When I remove the SingleChildScrollView I get the expected behavior but risk overflow. How do I construct my layouts so that I can get my desired outcome?

Doesn't matter which alignment you have set
alignment can be applied only on an intrinsic space, while scroll views provide an infinity of space.
how the row's elements can be justified or aligned within an infinity of space.
if you strongly need that scroll view: SingleChildScrollView. you must wrap your row with an intrinsic width widget like container or sized box, to make the alignment applied.

Wrap your Row inside a BoxConstraints like:
Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: const [
                Text("item1: item1_value"),
                Text("item2: item2_value"),
                Text("item3: item3_value")
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),


There would be no scrolling based on that...
